# error: 'set' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, declaration

I've already searched through this site and on Google, but I couldn't find anything helping me. I'm a total C++ noob and started coding yesterday, today I've spent couple of hours trying to figure out what I did wrong and I was already able to resolve like 10 errors (which is a lot in such a small code section, I know ._.). What did I do wrong? I do have small Java knowledge and a few scripting languages like LUA and Autoit3.

This is just a small program to test the GPIO pins on my Raspberry PI and to get used to the C++ syntax and to learn a little about programming.

Edit: The error occurrs twice, I've noted that down using comments

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Declaration of global variables
int delayTime;

//Gets executed once to setup parameters
static int setup() {
    delayTime = 750;
}

//Gets executed until ESC is pressed
static int program() {
    set(0, 1); //FIRST ERROR
    set(5, 0);
    delay(delayTime);
    set(0, 0);
    set(5, 1);
    delay(delayTime);
}


//Main function getting called at program start
int main() {
    bool running = true;

    setup();

    puts("Press 'STRG+C' to exit the program. Then run './off'");

    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
        return 1;

    pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);

    set(4, 1); //SECOND ERROR

    while (running) {
        program(); //Run the code above

    }

    digitalWriteByte(0);
    return 0;
}

//Shortcuts for basic functions
static int set(int pin, int state) {
    digitalWrite(pin, state);
    return 0;
}

static int get(int pin) {
    return digitalRead(pin);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `set()` before it has been declared. Either move the function up in the file, so that it is above the first place it is called, or add a forward declaration like this:

```
static int set(int pin, int state);
```

Comment: I was just about to answer the same exact thing.+1 for reading my mind

Comment: Thanks. The most impressive thing is that I did it without even realising :)

Answer (score 2):

C/C++ compilers are dumb — they proceed top-down.  At the time that you call `set()` from `main()`, the compiler still doesn't know what `set()` is yet, because it hasn't seen the definition.

One solution is to write an explicit declaration of `set()` before `main()` is defined.  An easier approach would be to move `main()` to the end, as is conventional — precisely because of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

C++ compilation is dependent on order. If you call something that was not yet declared, you get an error. Either move your functions body to a place before it's called, or place a forward declaration there.